# How to start Rack application with frozen string literals?

Tags: ruby, rack, ruby-2.3

I'm trying to run our application under ruby 2.3 using the new ruby feature for automatic frozen strings turned on globally.  [(Ruby 2.3)](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11473)  This is normally done by passing the argument to a ruby script when starting as follows:

```
ruby --enable-frozen-string-literal ruby_code_file.rb
```

Unfortunately, our application is started using rackup, and I've tried the following command:

```
rackup --enable-frozen-string-literal
```

But this does not appear to work.  How do I pass that parameter into Rack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass parameters for `ruby` to `rackup`, unfortunately. However, [`rackup`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/bin/rackup) is really, really simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rack"
Rack::Server.start
```

The simplest solution, then, is to duplicate this file in your project (in, say, `bin/frozen_rackup`) but change the first line to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby --enable-frozen-string-literal
```

Then make sure the file is executable (`chmod u+x bin/frozen_rackup`) and run `bin/frozen_rackup` instead of `rackup`.

P.S. I'm guessing that `--enable-frozen-string-literal` doesn't apply to gems your script requires, since it would break a lot of gems, but I haven't tested this and YMMV.

Comment: The flag looks like it _does_ apply to the gems you're including.